# p5.js : Image added multiple times while scaling down

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have the following p5.js code:

```
let minScale = 1
let maxScale = 5

let targetScale = minScale
let currentScale = targetScale

let idx = 0

function setup() {
  pixelDensity(1)
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)
  preload(IMG_PATHS, IMGS)
  frameRate(12)  
}

function draw() { 
  if (currentScale < targetScale) {
    currentScale += 0.01
  } else if (currentScale > targetScale) {
    currentScale -= 0.01
  }
  
  scale(currentScale)
    
  image(IMGS[idx], 0, 0)
  
  idx++
  
  if (idx === IMGS.length) {
    idx = 0
  }  
}

window.addEventListener('click', function() {
  targetScale = targetScale === maxScale ? minScale : maxScale
})
```

1. When I click I want to zoom-in.
2. When I click again I want to zoom out

**Issue**

It looks like `scale()` redraws the canvas without removing the previous ones. The issue is visible when zooming out. You will notice that multiple copies of the image remain on the canvas while zooming out.

Thank you in advance for your help.

You can see the issue [here](https://editor.p5js.org/Pixelik/sketches/7rXwMrkfB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing functions in p5.js generally do not clear the existing content. You can deliberately clear the entire canvas using [`clear()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/clear) or overwrite the entire thing with [`background(color)`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background). You can also clear selective portions of the canvas with [`erase()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/erase)/draw some shapes/[`noErase()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noErase).

As for zooming in and out centered on a certain point, that is a more complicated question and you should ask it separately.

Comment: Thanks `clear()` did the job :) I will open a separate question about zooming in/out of specific points because I still can't figure it out.